# Displaying progress bar while loading JSON from Web

Tags: android

I want to put  a progress bar for download Json
 When the download starts:

I want to display a dialog window for user.
After downloading , the progress bar disappears .

java codes:

```
public class GetJsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        { 
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
            progressDialog.setTitle("Processing...");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return getJson(urls[0]);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
             progressDialog.dismiss();
            try {

               jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);

                 JSONObject number = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);


                            download(); 


        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
   Log.e("aa", "erroor"+e.toString());
        }
    }

    }


  public  int download() throws JSONException
    {


        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_activity);
        final ProgressBar progressBar;
        Handler handler=new Handler();
        progressBar=(ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        progressBar.setMax(7);
        dialog.show();
         for( i=1;i<7;i++)
         {
         JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
           title[i-1]=object.getString("title");
            qustion[i-1]=object.getString("qustion");

            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    progressBar.setProgress(i);

                }
            });


         }
         handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

But when the program is executed
Does not display a progress bar
(Progress bar is GONE )

What is the problem ?

Comment: Use AsyncTask instead handler

Comment: method download is Inside AsyncTask

Comment: Your setup is wrong, in the asynctask: 1. `preExecute` show your dialog. 2. `doInbackground` put the method download. 3. In `PostExecute` hide the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your help
 Mentioned steps , do them

Answer (score 1):

In your asyncTask class (as you said in comment) display your progress in `onPreExecute` method , like this :

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
            progressBar.setMessage("Downloading...");
            progressBar.show();
        }
```

and dismiss it in onPostExecute method :

```
protected void onPostExecute() {
            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Read Ranjith comment first

Comment: I know this .
I want to progress I have two windows
1. progress bar to communicate with the server
2. To display the download
The first one works properly .
But not the latter .
i put  the full code

Comment: i hope this link can help you : https://github.com/simao/Android-DoubleProgressBar